# Importing URL Rewrite to IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-routing, iis-7.5

I am trying to run PimCore via IIS. However I am stumped at how to import the .htaccess file. I managed to import all the rules except these two in :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
```

It would really help if you folks can show me how to import these into the IIS 7 URL Rewrite engine.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the full htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/website/var/assets%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/var/assets%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^website/var/tmp.* - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^website/var/assets.* - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/.*/static.* - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^pimcore/static.* - [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^website/var/.*$ / [F,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/.*$ / [F,L]
RewriteRule ^pimcore/.*$ / [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Found this in the logs :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Interface' not found in D:\pimcoreroot\pimcore\lib\Zend\Controller\Router\Route\Abstract.php on line 39
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this myself.

In order to fix this routing issue. There is a threefold process for IIS 7.5. The first thing that needs to be done is that you naturally need URL Rewrite for IIS 7.5. When this is done, go to the web.config xml file and paste this in.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
         <rewrite>
             <rules>
                 <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url="^.*$" />
                     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                             matchType="IsFile" pattern=""
                             ignoreCase="false" />
                         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                             matchType="IsDirectory"
                             pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                     </conditions>
                     <action type="None" />
                 </rule>
                 <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url="^.*$" />
                     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                 </rule>
             </rules>
         </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

After doing so, go to IIS manager and go to the site you want to use pimcore on. Go to the import rules button on the right action panel. In the import rules text area which is the first text area from the top, paste this in :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/website/var/assets%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/var/assets%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^website/var/tmp.* - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^website/var/assets.* - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/.*/static.* - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^pimcore/static.* - [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^website/var/.*$ / [F,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/.*$ / [F,L]
RewriteRule ^pimcore/.*$ / [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

After doing so, click apply and this will allow pimcore's routing to work on your IIS site :)