# How to forward mydomain.com to mydomain.net web site

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, forwarding

"mydomain**.com**" is hosted on iis 7.5 and referenced at google,
For the same website, I need to use a second domain name: "mydomain**.net**" .
I would like to redirect people who type "mydomain.com" to "mydomain.net" without losing previous google referencing,

please how can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which language and platform did u write the site? In other words, is it a CMS or is it written in MVC or something? Have u looked into other Q&A posts like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286597/importing-url-rewrite-to-iis-7-5 ?

Comment: I made the site using simple HTML, without use of CMS or any other language

Comment: Is there any site hosted at mydomain.com or is it just a domainname with no hosting? In the second case i would just add a A-record in the DNS. To be honest i don't have experience with rewrites

Comment: There is only one site hosted at mydomain.net, mydomain.com would serve only to forward people to mydomain.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within IIS it is necessary to duplicate the `mydomain.net` web site folder, and to link the duplicated web site to `mydomain.com`, then select `mydomain.com` and click on HTTP redirect (which should be enabled from IIS features) then "redirect requests to this destination checked, and make also "Redirect all requests to exact destination..." checked, with behavior status code:"Permanent 301 redirect".

You can find a further explanation here:

http://www.windowshostingasp.net/windows_hosting_forums/showthread.php?t=35