# Website first load too slow

Tags: web, load, pagespeed

My websites (HTML and ASP.NET MVC) are hosted on a IIS 7.5 VPS
their first load is always too slow, even requested from localhost, then navigation speed between the web sites pages is good.
please what to do to increase first load speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can always set the Idle Time-out of the application pool to 0 which is default 20 minutes. It's under advanced settings. That way the first load won't be often.

Comment: I have changed to 0 the Idle timeout and the load time decreased. As I do not know well this parameter, do it has other repercussions?

Comment: It keeps the application pool alive and U can still set the recycling to specific times, dor example at nighttime. And there are several services available that send a request to your site. We are hosting several sites and always set the idle time out to 0

Comment: Now it's Ok, after several attempts site load is fast. Thank you for your help. I would like you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456721/how-to-forward-mydomain-com-to-mydomain-net-web-site) please

Answer (score 0):

First load tends to require a compilation of webpages (aspx or razor).  You can precompile these.   Also, if you have a database repository, often this gets initialized on first load, and depending on whats been done there, this also can be slow.  ( but most often can be optimized )

Comment: Hi Keith, I have also a simple HTML website without any database which take too much time to load.

Answer (score 0):

A would check the page load with [Trace](http://knucklebones.blogspot.com/2010/11/enable-tracing-in-aspnet-mvc.html).

---

Yeah, Keith is right.