# Why is my webpage load time more than 10 secs even with 98% speed performance score?

Tags: performance, iis, dns, pagespeed, asp-net-mvc-1

Is there any way to identify why this [website](http://eamcetexams.com) initial loading is very slow? I have checked in my each and every part of the HTML structure and code (Requests, Response).

It’s loading very fast after first time loading completes.
I have performed page speed optimization then followed [page speed rules](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules).  After that my page speed score in GTMetrix as below picture. But still initial loading is very slow.

What would be the reason? How can we resolve this type of speed issues?
[image]

Comment: I Checked http://www.bytecheck.com for the Time to First Byte and that doesn't seem to be a problem either. FYI: the website is loading fast for me

Comment: You are using `marquee` tag in your website. This [might not work in near fututre](http://eamcetexams.com/). And I suspect even if it works fine on all mobile browsers at present. You should some jquery plugin instead. E.g. http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Text-Scrolling-Plugin-for-jQuery-Marquee.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is an issue with your "cdn" subdomain.

Comment: Where can i see that DNS/ subdomain resolution problems and how can we fix?

Comment: After checking your site on firebug, it isnt DNS.  It is however waiting on response from your cdn subdomain.  Is the subdomain on same server?

Comment: Yes, subdomain is on the same server.

Comment: Do you have any issues with slow ftp transfers?

Comment: If your using ASP.NET you could try setting the Idle Timeout of the application pool to 0 as in this post. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456994/website-first-load-too-slow?rq=1)

Comment: Any word on what happened with this?

Comment: No issues with ftp transfers. Application pool is already set to 0. but still initial load is very slow but loading very fast after fist time load complets.

Comment: I just tried your site again and it loaded fast on the first try.  What browser are you using?